# On a m1 Mac, difference between homebrew on /usr/local and /opt/homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, filesystem, apple-silicon

With a m1 Mac, home-brew does not store things in /usr/local, but /opt/homebrew. Is there any difference to switch homebrew over to /usr/local? I think the only reason would be that when you google something you don't have to change /usr/local to /opt/homebrew. Are there any other practical reasons other than consistency?

Comment: Homebrew changed it because they could not make it install into /usr/local. They would very much appreciate a patch that shows the how to do it.

Comment: So /usr/local is the way to go, but it can't be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location

> Homebrew’s pre-built binary packages (known as bottles) of many formulae can only be used if you install in the default installation prefix, otherwise they have to be built from source. Building from source takes a long time, is prone to failure, and is not supported.

Also

> The prefix /opt/homebrew was chosen to allow installations in /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and /usr/local for Rosetta 2 to coexist and use bottles.